# "Trivial" assymptotic bound in Gallagher's paper

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

In his paper *On the distribution of primes in short intervals*, right before equation 9, Gallagher states that $$\sum_{d|D}\frac{\mu^2(d)*C^{\omega(d)}}{\phi(d)}\sum_{\substack{e\gt x/d \\ \text{(e,D)=1}}}\frac{\mu^2(e)*C^{\omega(e)}}{\phi^2(e)}\ll\sum_{d|D}\frac{\mu^2(d)*C^{\omega(d)}}{\phi(d)}\frac{d}{x}{log}^B x$$ where C is a fixed constant, $\omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$, $\mu$ is the Mobius function and D is given by $$D = \sum_{i\lt j}(d_i-d_j)$$ in which $1\leq d_1\lt ... \lt d_r \leq h$, h being a fixed positive constant and the $d_i$'s are integers.

To my understanding the notation $\ll$ means : does not grow faster than, with respect to the variable $x$. The paper can be found here : [cambridge.org](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/on-the-distribution-of-primes-in-short-intervals/DCE557AC8750333E68426FCEEC11858C)

What I can't understand is how one gets $$\sum_{\substack{e\gt x/d \\ \text{(e,D)=1}}}\frac{\mu^2(e)*C^{\omega(e)}}{\phi^2(e)}\ll\frac{d}{x}{log}^B x$$

Comment: Unless we have access to the paper, to which you have only given us a partial citation, we cannot help you with this.

Comment: A standard method is Selberg-Delange method. This begins with writing $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n) C^{w(n)}}{\phi(n)^2 n^s}$$ as a product of a power of the Riemann zeta function and a function whose abscissa of absolute convergence is $\sigma>1-\delta$ for some $\delta>0$.